# Writing Entries in a VB Dictionary into a Text File

Tags: vb.net, file, dictionary, streamwriter

I'm working on VB in college and am running into a snag with one of my assignments.  Can someone help?  I'm aiming to try to take the following dictionary code:

```
Public Class Inventory
Public ItemInventory As New Dictionary(Of String, Item)

Public Function iItem(ByVal key As String) As Item
    Return ItemInventory(key)
End Function

Public Sub addItem(ByVal item As String, ByVal Desc As String, ByVal DRate As Double, ByVal WRate As Double, _
                   ByVal MRate As Double, ByVal Quantity As Integer)
    With ItemInventory
        .Add(item, New Item(item, Desc, DRate, WRate, MRate, Quantity))
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub removeItem(ByVal item As String)

    With ItemInventory
        .Remove(item)
    End With
End Sub

Public Function returnKeys() As String()
    Dim Keys() As String

    With ItemInventory
        Keys = .Keys.ToList.ToArray
    End With

    Return Keys
End Function
End Class
```

Not pretty, I know, but it gets the job done, that's all I aim to do.  Now a bit of this also has to do with displaying a dictionary item in the program, which I'm also having issues with, however, I'd like to take this one step at a time, so we'll get to that later, if possible.

As per writing, this is my current code for reading and writing:

```
    Imports System.IO

Public Class InventoryFile
    Public Sub RFile(ByVal FPath As String, ByRef dInventory As Inventory)
        Dim infile As StreamReader = File.OpenText(FPath)
        Dim entireLine As String = infile.ReadLine()
        Dim fields() As String = entireLine.Split(","c)

        While infile.EndOfStream
            Dim dItem As New Item
            dItem.ID = fields(0)
            dItem.Description = fields(1)
            dItem.Daily = fields(2)
            dItem.Weekly = fields(3)
            dItem.Monthly = fields(4)
            dItem.Quantity = fields(5)

            'AddItem
            dInventory.addItem(dItem.ID, dItem.Description, dItem.Daily, dItem.Weekly, _
                               dItem.Monthly, dItem.Quantity)

        End While
    End Sub

    Public Sub WFile(ByVal FPath As String, ByRef dInventory As Inventory)
        Dim outfile As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(FPath)

        For Each Item As KeyValuePair(Of String, Item) In dInventory.ItemInventory



        Next
    End Sub


End Class
```

I hope that posted right.  Now, reading in, as far as I understand, works just fine, in terms of a file going into a dictionary, however 'WFile', my StreamWriter, is what's got me stumped.  Can someone help me with that?  Likewise, its supposed to close and write to the file upon closing, and my only code for the close button is the Me.Close() command.  How would I write a trigger to make the program write to the file?  Know that the main form code, and my 'InventoryFile' are both separate classes, so this has to be done by referencing the other classes in question

Comment: One fairly major correction might be needed. The while loop in RFile doesn't encompass the Readline.  If your file only has one line your code will work.  However more than one line and nothing will get added to the dictionary or at best only the last line.  Use `While Not infile.EndOfStream` and encompass the Readline statement as well.

Comment: Ah!  I knew I was forgetting that part!  Thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

Try this to write each dictionary key/value pair on a single line in the file:

```
Dim fs As FileStream

' Open the stream and write to it.
fs = File.OpenWrite(FPath)

For Each Item As KeyValuePair(Of String, Item) In dInventory.ItemInventory
    fs.Write("{0}:{1}", Item.Key, Item.Value)
Next
```

UPDATE:

Since `Item` is both the variable used in the loop and the name of a class, change it to another name like `singleItem` and then pull out the other pieces of information from the `Value` portion of the key/value pair, because the `Value` is actually an `Item` class object, like this:

```
Dim fs As FileStream

' Open the stream and write to it.
fs = File.OpenWrite(FPath)

For Each singleItem As KeyValuePair(Of String, Item) In dInventory.ItemInventory
    fs.Write("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}:{4}:{5}:{6}", singleItem.Key, singleItem.Value.ID, singleItem.Value.Description, singleItem.Value.Daily, singleItem.Value.Weekly, singleItem.Value.Monthly, singleItem.Value.Quantity)
Next
```

Comment: Well, that's just it.  I've got the key in the dictionary, so I can use that first part, but the description and additional values are all in another class.  Is it possible to use your method with the 'Item.Value' that you mentioned as the class that contains said details on the entries?

Comment: I think part of the problem is you are using the name `Item` as both a variable name in the `For Each` loop, as well as `Item` as the name of a class, see `UPDATE:` in answer.

Comment: Well, yeah, but VB doesn't mark the variable in the code as a class; as far as I understand, I need to do that by doing a declaration of the variable to stand in for the class reference, an example being the declaration in the While loop.  I'll still give it a go and see how it works.  Now, I just need to get the content to display...

Comment: Also, just noticed the open file bit.  That I've got part of the load sequence when the program starts, so that's taken care of.  This in mind, I need to have the program make a new file if one isn't selected.  How would I put in the default name that the program will use if it needs to make a new text file?

Comment: Well, as odd as it seems, I just now tried this method.  Yes, it looks like it'd work, however the 'WriteLine' part doesn't seem to work.  It's giving me an error, saying "'WriteLine' is not a member of 'System.IO.FileStream'".  Did I miss something?

Comment: @NFSRacer - ah yes that should be just a `Write()`, updated answer.

Comment: That's actually throwing me an error when I do this ForNext code:

`For Each singleItem As KeyValuePair(Of String, Item) In Inventory.ItemInventory
            outfile.Write("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}", singleItem.Key, singleItem.Value.ID, _
                              singleItem.Value.Description, singleItem.Value.Daily, singleItem.Value.Weekly, _
                              singleItem.Value.Monthly, singleItem.Value.Quantity)
        Next`

Not sure how else to display it, sorry.  Error keeps coming up, saying there's an overflow in arguments.  Any fixes?

Answer (score 0):

In order to create the format your RFile procedure can read you need something like this:

```
 For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, Item) In dInventory.ItemInventory

    ' using Karl's compact approach, but add commas 
    ' since your Read expects them
    outfile.Write("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}...", kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ID, _
        kvp.Value.Description, ... kvp.Value.Quantity.Tostring)

    ' the Value part of the fvp is another class, right?  `Value.XXX` should drill
    ' into it to get to the members 

 Next
 outfile.flush
 outfile.close        ' look into 'Using...'
```

Thats NOT how I would do it, look into serialization for a less fragile way to read/write the data.  It is basically meant for just this sort of thing: save class data for later, and it is not that hard to use.

as for hooking it up, the button click would just call `Inventory.WFile`

Comment: Would I call 'Inventory.WFile' within the 'Me.Close' parameter, or through another method?

Comment: Call `Inventory.WFile` whenever it makes sense to save the data.  You might want to call it after X number of changes have been made.  To save it as part of ending, call it in the Close button click event before you do the Me.Close.

Comment: Right, but I'm trying to remember how to simply call on it from the main form.  What sort of key word would I use?  Simply 'Call'?

Comment: your class has it as a public method, so call it using the instance name of `InventoryFile` (your code doesnt show/tell).  Something like 'InvenFile.Wfile`.  BTW the pieces in `InventoryFile` should propbably be a part of the main `Inventory` class: a well written class ought to know how to read and write the data it is managing

Comment: I thought about doing that, but I found that the assignment requires the reading and writing code to be in a separate class to the Inventory code.  A little weird, I know, but hell, I don't ask questions about what's in the text book, unless it's part of an issue that the teacher is having with the examples in the presentation.